# How to define a second Entity Framework Core relationship to the same foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I have the following entity relation diagram, I have to translate to a C# model, later used within an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application and handled by Entity Framework Core.

[image: entity relation diagram]

There are two entities (`Product`, and `ProductVersion`).
A `Product` may have none, one or multiple `ProductVersion`; this relation is called *Versions* and *Product* (the right side of the diagram).
A `Product` may also have none or one `ProductVersion` which represent the current version; this relation is called *CurrentVersion* and *Product* (the left side of the diagram).

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        var optBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        optBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyContext");
        MyContext context = new MyContext(optBuilder.Options);
        context.Add(new Product { Name = "First Product" });
    }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
         : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ProductVersion> ProductVersions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOne(p => p.CurrentVersion).WithOne(pv => pv.Product);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(p => p.Versions).WithOne(pv => pv.Product);
        }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid CurrentVersionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrentVersionId")]
    public virtual ProductVersion CurrentVersion { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual List<ProductVersion> Versions { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVersion
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public Version Version { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a .NET Fiddle link for quick experiments: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r1bhGs

The error message is the following:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a
>   relationship between 'Product.Versions' and 'ProductVersion.Product',
>   because there already is a relationship between
>   'ProductVersion.Product' and 'Product.CurrentVersion'. Navigation
>   properties can only participate in a single relationship.

Is there really no way around a duplicate field for `ProductVersion`, lets call it `CurrentVersionProductId`, or is there a *fluent* solution to this?

---

In a second attempt, I tried to implement only a `CurrentProduct` navigational property.

```cs
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOne(p => p.CurrentVersion).WithOne(pv => pv.CurrentProduct);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(p => p.Versions).WithOne(pv => pv.Product);
    }
```

```cs
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid CurrentVersionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrentVersionId")]
    public virtual ProductVersion CurrentVersion { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual List<ProductVersion> Versions { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVersion
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public Version Version { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual Product CurrentProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the .NET Fiddle for this code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zkZwgF

However, I ran into the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type
>   'Version' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use
>   a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.

Why have to be `Version` the primary key, when `Id` is already marked as the primary `[Key]`?

Comment: The second exception is saying that `Version` class does not have any attribute marked as `[Key]`. It is not about marking `Version` attribute as key.

Comment: @akg179 : Ah, ok... that makes more sense. So EF thinks that `Version` is a `ComplexeType` and does not try to use `ToString()` and `Parse(value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding to the latter:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductVersion>().OwnsOne(p => p.Version);
```

[Owned Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)

Your `Version` property is of type `Systme.Version` which EF recognizes as a navigation property and it can't determine a primary key for this entity, cause you have not defined it in any way.